# Buffer overrun comment from CODESONAR on stl::map iterator usage

Tags: c++, stl, buffer-overrun

```
....
wstring wstrFirst;
INFO_t* pstInfo = NULL;
INFO_MAP::const_iterator itrReqInfoEnd = RequestedInfoMap_i.end();
for( INFO_MAP::const_iterator itrReqInfo = RequestedInfoMap_i.begin();
     itrReqInfo != itrReqInfoEnd; 
     ++itrReqInfo )
{
    wstrFirst = itrReqInfo->first;
    pstInfo = itrReqInfo->second;
    ...
```

Please see above code snippet.
I am running CODESONAR (static analysis tool) on this.
My problem is that, at the last line (`pstInfo = itrReqInfo->second;`), CODESONAR shows following error:

> This code reads past the end of the buffer pointed to by itrReqInfo->.
>
> . itrReqInfo-> evaluates to &wstrFirst._Bx.
>
> . The first byte read is at offset 48 from the beginning of the buffer pointed to by itrReqInfo->, whose capacity is 48 bytes.
>
> . The offset exceeds the capacity.
>
> . The overrun occurs in stack memory. The issue can occur if the highlighted code executes.

(here the highlighted code means `pstInfo = itrReqInfo->second;`)

Is it false-positive? If not, how can I fix that?

Comment: So what happens when you execute the highlighted code? Is everything OK? What does Valgrind say about all that?

Comment: The code is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `itrReqInfo` is a `const_iterator` and the `for` is only walking it through the `map` from beginning to end, don't see how anything can be reading past a buffer limit. But would need to see a more complete example of this error to know for sure.